# Получить в ответ не все данные YII2 API

Tags: php, yii2

Если я посредством API обращаюсь к контроллеру я получаю ответ с данными от пользователя.
Но в ответе **все** данные. Могу ли я как то выдать ответ сервером данные пользователя,  только без password, auth_key.

```
public function actionIndex($id, $auth_key) {
        $user = User::find()
            ->where(['id' => $id])
            ->where(['auth_key' => $auth_key])
            ->one();
        if ($user != null) {
            return ['user' => $user];
        } else {
            return ['error' => 'Client has no valid login cookies.'];
        }
}
```

Comment: Можете, если не будете отдавать наружу модель целиком

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток

Порекомендую вам самый простой и очевидный вариант.

Сделать метод getApiData у модели:

`public function getApiData()
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id
    ];
}`

И вызвать его не возвращая модель полностью

`public function actionIndex($id, $auth_key) {
        $user = User::find()
            ->where(['id' => $id])
            ->where(['auth_key' => $auth_key])
            ->one();
        if ($user != null) {
            return ['user' => $user->getApiData()];
        } else {
            return ['error' => 'Client has no valid login cookies.'];
        }
}`

Удачной разработки!

Answer (score 0):

```
unset($user->auth_key, $user->password_hash ,$user->password_reset_token);
                return ['user' => $user];
```

Answer (score 0):

Для начала почитайте как правильно переопределить actionIndex()
[https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/rest-controllers.md#Настройка-действий-](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/rest-controllers.md#%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9-)

Былобы неплохо ещё и запрос поправить

```
$user = User::find()
    ->where([
        'id' => $id,
        'auth_key' => $auth_key
    ])
    ->one();
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого нужно переопределить метод *fields* в вашей модели. Более подробно можно почитать [в документации](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html#overriding-fields).

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.